# EF6 "No migrations have been applied to the target database."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In an mvc5 application, I created a CodeFirst data model, and performed several migrations on it.

I then refactored my project, and moved all the data/migrations classes to a new project, which is referenced by my presentation tier.

The dbcontext successfully connects and performs read/write operations on the DB after the project change.

When I made a minor change to the model and ran `add-migration`, the EF created a migration with the code to create the database from the beginning, like it didn't "see" the existing tables.

Of course, when i ran

```
Get-Migrations  -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationDbContext
```

i got

```
No migrations have been applied to the target database.
```

The `__MigrationHistory` in the DB is intact and the migrations/configuration classes namespaces didn't change. Also, apparently, the ConnectionString is OK, otherwise he would have trouble working with the db and i would get the "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created" or similar error.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comment, I specify the exact connection string in the DbContext constructor, and not the connectionstirng name in web.config, as it was in the original mvc project.

Still no history/changes in the db when running Get-Migrations and update-databse.

when I run `Get-Migrations -ConfigurationTypeName My_Namespace.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext.ConfigurationDbContext`

I get

```
No migrations have been applied to the target database.
```

If I try to specify the connection string

```
Get-Migrations -ConfigurationTypeName My_Namespace.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext.ConfigurationDbContext -ConnectionString "Server=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_catalog;User Id=my_user;Password=my_pass" -ConnectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" -verbose -debug
```

the PM gets stuck on `>>` sign, until I restart or clear the window...

if I omit the `ConnectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"`, the console asks me to enter it, and after I enter, it shows connection to the correct db,

```
Target database is: 'my_catalog (DataSource: my_server Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit)
```

but still no migrations...

```
No migrations have been applied to the target database.
```

Why can it be and what can be done to further investigate/resolve this issue?

**EDIT 2:**

the constructor of my dbcontext is simple:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(
            "Server=my_server_name;Initial Catalog=my_db_name;UserId=my_username;Password=my_password" 
       )
    {}

    public DbSet<Model1> Model1Entities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model2> Model2Entities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model3> Model3Entities { get; set; }



}
```

it is based on IdentityDbContext as in the template mvc5 applicaiton, because I didn't want to create a different dbcontext for it.

and the ConfigurationDbContext is automatic

```
 internal sealed class ConfigurationDbContext : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ConfigurationDbContext()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you run the migration against a test instance of your db, does it recreate the whole thing? Or just apply the change? (i'm working on a EF6 + mvc5) but using auto migrations during dev with no problems

Comment: i ran an "update" and it made no changes to the db. when run with -verbose, it shows that "Target database is: 'DefaultConnection' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention)", and then all the sql statements with no exceptions. it should run against the sql server with my connection string...

Comment: Are you passing the connection string into the DbContext constructor? If you don't, it will bash on and work against DefaultConnection without an error.

Comment: wow! oh man, really, while replying I checked the dbcontext constructor just to make sure, and discovered that I passed not the connectionstring, but the connectionstring name as it was stated in the web.config, which now exists in a completely separate project! while working from the mvc project, everything was fine, but when running update-database, ef of course didn't see it. thanks!

Comment: well, stuck again. when I passed the connection string itself to the dbcontext constructor, there was the same effect - no migrations. then i try to run "Get-Migrations -ConfigurationTypeName My_Namespace.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext.ConfigurationDbContext -ConnectionString "Server=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_catalog;User Id=my_user;Password=my_pass" -ConnectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" -verbose -debug"

and the PM gets stuck on >> sign, until I restart or clear the window...

Comment: Well, if I omit the ConnectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient", the console asks me to enter it, and after I enter, it shows connection to the correct db, but still no migrations...

Comment: post some code, mainly the constructor for your DbContext

Comment: posted in the edit. thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46858/discussion-between-james-and-alex440)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the answer is that somehow during the refactor the namespace of `ConfigurationDbContext` changed from

```
demo10.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext
```

to

```
demo10.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext.ConfigurationDbContext
```

and the `ContextKey` column of the `__MigrationHistory` table should be the `ConfigurationDbContext` namespace (you can omit the DbContext, like to have

```
 demo10.Migrations.Configuration
```

in the table for

```
demo10.Migrations.ConfigurationDbContext
```

namespace).

Answer (score 8):

Leaving an answer here as I had a similar problem that wasn't solved by this:

I had the password wrong in the app.config I was using against a different environment. Get-Migrations doesn't give you an error about failed credentials, it just tells you "No migrations have been applied to the target database", which is hugely misleading.

Hopefully someone else who comes across this will discover it's as simple as a typo in their connection string!

edit: the irony of typo-ing the word typo in an answer about my typo.

Comment: Similarly, I also got this issue in Azure due to the firewall settings we have setup to prevent outside access. Adding my client IP address to Azure and then retrying fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues in development having the __MigrationHistory table open in SQL server Management Studio... 
After closing the table (which was NOT open for edit, just select), somehow fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in with an edge case of my own: check to see if your DB is in mixed mode or purely in Windows Auth mode.

Had a 2014 install go sideways such that sa was disabled and there was no Windows account authorized (client had a hosting upgrade to 2014, so I had to match it). I managed to stand it back up and regain Windows account access (real edge case voodoo shit), but didn’t realize it was stuck in Windows Auth mode only. Once I switched it back to mixed mode, I suddenly had a connection again. D’oh!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now and the issue was that my sa password had expired and needed to be reset. I was still logged in from a previous session so I could run queries no problem but when I disconnected and reconnected I had to reset my password! Took me an hour to figure that out though :/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when i split the code into multiple projects. Solved by seting the default project of the solution to the one that have the correct connection string.
Get the hint by running the command:

```
get-migrations -Verbose
eflocation\ef6.exe migrations list --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly dataproject \project.dll --project-dir dataproject\ --language C# --data-dir defaultproject\App_Data --root-namespace dataproject --config defaultproject\Web.config
```

The Web.config or app.config file that you see after running the command should be taked from the default project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I changed the name of my project.  I had also recently rebooted the server.

So, I had to do two things to solve the problem:

1. Start the SQL Server service
2. Create an Update query for the
   __MigrationHistory table to change the value of the **ContextKey column** from Old_ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration to New_ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration.

That sorted it for me.